Excel wrongly counts blank cells
I have an Excel sheet with some data, and no formulas were used in the sheet as far as I know. I first tried counting blank cells using the COUNTBLANK() function to determine how many cells had no data in a specific column. However, the result didn’t match what I calculated using R.

I then used a pivot table, but it gave the same result, which I realized was misleading because Excel was counting certain cells as having values, even though they appeared blank. Interestingly, when I wrote #N/A in one cell and then removed it, Excel counted that cell as blank, but it hadn’t recognized it as blank earlier.
What could be causing this discrepancy?

Are you sure that the cells are blank and there are for example no spaces in them? What the results of ISBLANK() for that range/column?

What is the formula in O3? Also, you can export the sheet as .CSV, then open it with notepad to find out what the content of the cells really are. Then you can truly see if they are blank or not, which they probably aren't.

Weird enough, ISBLANK() yields FALSE on the blank cells.

ISBLANK checks if the cell is actually empty, COUNTBLANK counts also cells with empty text, COUNTA counts cells that are not blank, also with empty text.

="" is not equal to blank. So the result of something showing nothing is actually something saying it's nothing. You can check for =N(LEN(range)=0) or =N(A2="")

Thanks everyone. I solved the issue by filtering the blank cells for each column, and then deleting the cell contents (which I cannot see -_-).

You might want to post it (in a little more detail) as an answer- rolling in the content from any relevant comments, rather than letting the solution moulder in comments

Thanks for your sharing, maybe you could write an answer.

Thanks Reddy Lutonadio and MGonet for the comments. I figured out the solution to be manually deleting the empty cells (appears empty, but truly not).
Basically, when I used the ISBLANK() function to see whether the cells are truly blank, it returned FALSE. That's why the =COUNTBLANK() could not count correct number of blank cells nor could the pivot table.
But I noticed that whenever I press the DEL button, that cell shows TRUE to the ISBLANK() function. So, I sorted the columns from larger to smaller and then hit the delete key by selecting the blank cells using SHIFT and CTRL key. May I could use filter too, but didn't bother as the previous trick worked already.
